# Copy large file to pc formatted ntfs external drive using a mac

Tags: macos, mac, ntfs, vmware-fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I share an external hard drive between a Mac and a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1549/how-can-i-share-an-external-hard-drive-between-a-mac-and-a-pc)

I run VMWare fusion on my macbook pro and one of my virtual drives has reached about 36Gb. I wanted to put the file on an external hard disk I just bought so that I could take it into work and run it there. I formatted my hard disk with NTFS on my PC and then tried to copy the file from my mac onto the drive but it wouldn't allow me too. I kept getting an error code of type 0. Is there a reason I can't copy large files to an NTFS drive on the mac?

I then partitioned the drive to Mac OS Extended and this allowed me to copy the files to the drive, but now I can't see the hard disk on my PC without installing MacDrive. I was hoping the whole process would be a little more seamless. Is there any way around all this kerfuffle?

TIA

Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

You need [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) because MacOS X can only read from NTFS, not write.

This question is a [duplicate.](https://superuser.com/questions/63763/i-have-recieved-an-external-harddrive-how-can-i-use-it-between-my-pc-and-mac-si)

Comment: Which is itself a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1549/how-can-i-share-an-external-hard-drive-between-a-mac-and-a-pc