# External Harddrive or NAS for mac/win home

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, wireless-router

I want to backup data both from my macbook and windows desktop. Is it possible using a NAS like 
LaCie Network Space 2 to backup data from both the machines on the server. I 'm guessing I will have to partition the drive and then store the data separately on the respective drives.

Secondly would an external harddrive attached to wifi router be a good option as compared to using NAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lacie NAS you mentioned above uses FAT32, which your Mac and your Windows laptops will be able to access the same data. No need for separate partitions. BUt of course FAT32 has limitations (file size for one). You could format it to NTFS or NFS+ but then you would have to use 3rd party software to access the drive... or do the 2 partitions. [How can I share an external hard drive between a Mac and a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1549/how-can-i-share-an-external-hard-drive-between-a-mac-and-a-pc)

NAS has alot of benefits compared to just using an external hd. Depends on the NAS and what you want. Redundancy & speed w/ raid, security...remote access. External HD is simple but basically a dumb brother compared to a NAS.

Comment: Is  LaCie Network Space 2 the best option for a mac/win configuration? I dont want to shell out lot of money on building my own system. I know that lot of the products dont allow swapping HD in case of failure and it needs to be sent back to vendor for fixing.

Comment: Best option? Depends on what you want to store. If your storing large files (video/backup-images) than no it wouldn't. You would have to format it to NTFS or NFS+.

Comment: You can add an internal hd to your desktop to have a simple backup drive without the need of an external device. Depending on your motherboard you could add two hds and raid them. Or even go the other way and just use an online backup service and not deal with buying any hardware. Well if use a RAID that is redundant than when one hd fails you still have the other until you get the bad hd fixed.